# Why Compiled RegEx performance is slower than Intrepreted RegEx?

Tags: .net, regex, performance

I run into this article:

[Performance: Compiled vs. Interpreted Regular Expressions](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:allben.net/post/2009/08/06/Performance-Compiled-vs-Interpreted-Regular-Expressions.aspx), I modified the sample code to compile 1000 Regex and then run each 500 times to take advantage of precompilation, however even in that case interpreted RegExes run 4 times faster!

<strike>This means `RegexOptions.Compiled` option is completely useless, actually even worse, it's slower!</strike> Big difference was due to JIT, after solving JIT compiled regex in the the following code still performs a little bit slow and doesn't make sense to me but [@Jim in the answers provided a much cleaner version which works as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004819/why-compiled-regex-performance-is-slower-than-intrepreted-regex/6005226#6005226).

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

**Code, taken & modified from the blog post:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegExTester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                CheckForMatches("some random text with email address, address@domain200.com" + i.ToString());    
            }


            double msTaken = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine("Full Run: " + msTaken);


            startTime = DateTime.Now;

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                CheckForMatches("some random text with email address, address@domain200.com" + i.ToString());
            }


            msTaken = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine("Full Run: " + msTaken);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }


        private static List<Regex> _expressions;
        private static object _SyncRoot = new object();

        private static List<Regex> GetExpressions()
        {
            if (_expressions != null)
                return _expressions;

            lock (_SyncRoot)
            {
                if (_expressions == null)
                {
                    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

                    List<Regex> tempExpressions = new List<Regex>();
                    string regExPattern =
                        @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]*@{0}$";

                    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
                    {
                        tempExpressions.Add(new Regex(
                            string.Format(regExPattern,
                            Regex.Escape("domain" + i.ToString() + "." +
                            (i % 3 == 0 ? ".com" : ".net"))),
                            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));//  | RegexOptions.Compiled
                    }

                    _expressions = new List<Regex>(tempExpressions);
                    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
                    double msTaken = endTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds;
                    Console.WriteLine("Init:" + msTaken);
                }
            }

            return _expressions;
        }

        static  List<Regex> expressions = GetExpressions();

        private static void CheckForMatches(string text)
        {

            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;


                foreach (Regex e in expressions)
                {
                    bool isMatch = e.IsMatch(text);
                }


            DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
            //double msTaken = endTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds;
            //Console.WriteLine("Run: " + msTaken);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `StopWatch` should be used instead of `DateTime` for benchmarks.

Comment: @Domenic Agreed, I used the code from blogpost, shouldn't affect the outcome of this test in a useful manner though

Comment: The biggest problem is that the first time a compiled Regex will be executed, it will have to be JIT compiled. The JIT compiling is taking more time than actually looking for matches! If you run `CheckForMatches` once before you initialize `startTime`, you will see that the times are much closer.

Comment: @Gabe Good point Gabe, I updated the code, basically run twice and I take the second execution times. I assume this will solve JIT issue. It's still slower though but much much close this time.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Compiled regular expressions match faster when used as intended. As others have pointed out, the idea is to compile them once and use them many times. The construction and initialization time are [amortized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) out over those many runs.

I created a much simpler test that will show you that compiled regular expressions are unquestionably faster than not compiled.

```
    const int NumIterations = 1000;
    const string TestString = "some random text with email address, address@domain200.com";
    const string Pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]*@domain0\\.\\.com$";
    private static Regex NormalRegex = new Regex(Pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    private static Regex CompiledRegex = new Regex(Pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    private static Regex DummyRegex = new Regex("^.$");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var DoTest = new Action<string, Regex, int>((s, r, count) =>
            {
                Console.Write("Testing {0} ... ", s);
                Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                {
                    bool isMatch = r.IsMatch(TestString + i.ToString());
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("{0:N0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            });

        // Make sure that DoTest is JITed
        DoTest("Dummy", DummyRegex, 1);
        DoTest("Normal first time", NormalRegex, 1);
        DoTest("Normal Regex", NormalRegex, NumIterations);
        DoTest("Compiled first time", CompiledRegex, 1);
        DoTest("Compiled", CompiledRegex, NumIterations);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Done. Press Enter:");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Setting `NumIterations` to 500 gives me this:

```
Testing Dummy ... 0 ms
Testing Normal first time ... 0 ms
Testing Normal Regex ... 1 ms
Testing Compiled first time ... 13 ms
Testing Compiled ... 1 ms
```

With 5 million iterations, I get:

```
Testing Dummy ... 0 ms
Testing Normal first time ... 0 ms
Testing Normal Regex ... 17,232 ms
Testing Compiled first time ... 17 ms
Testing Compiled ... 15,299 ms
```

Here you see that the compiled regular expression is at least 10% faster than the not compiled version.

It's interesting to note that if you remove the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` from your regular expression, the results from 5 million iterations are even more striking:

```
Testing Dummy ... 0 ms
Testing Normal first time ... 0 ms
Testing Normal Regex ... 12,869 ms
Testing Compiled first time ... 14 ms
Testing Compiled ... 8,332 ms
```

Here, the compiled regular expression is 35% faster than the not compiled regular expression.

In my opinion, the blog post you reference is simply a flawed test.

Comment: Good one, thanks, especially IgnoreCase effect is quite interesting as well.

Comment: Any particular reason for not making the `DoTest` an actual named method?

Comment: @Dyppl: No. It was just easier to make it an `Action`.

Comment: Also note that the locale that these times are using has a comma for the decimal point. For us yanks, the times are 17.232ms and 15.299ms

Comment: @IDisposable: Actually, the comma is the thousands separator. It's 17 seconds and change, and 15 seconds and change. The numbers reported are total time for 5 million iterations, not average time per iteration.

Comment: @JimMischel I know it's an old post, nevertheless, what he meant was whether using `,` or `.` depends on the locale. In my country 10.001 means ten thous one. While in other countries it means 10 and 1 permille. I think anyone can imagine that a (simple) single match doesn't take 17+ms given your earlier numbers. He just meant that in our locale it's written as `17.232` and `15.299`.

Comment: Compiled are slower for me - http://share.linqpad.net/uk6wie.linq. Also notice that even if you are not using Compiled they are still Compiled and cached for you - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zbs0h2f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @PiotrPerak: I don't see how your code differs from mine, so I don't understand why you posted it. Perhaps you meant to post the output with timings? If your results are different than mine and you're wondering why, you should post a question. I don't see how the regex cache is relevant to this discussion. If it's being used, then it still doesn't perform as well as explicitly compiled expressions. At least not in this test case.

Comment: I just posted it so others can test it easy. Your post is very old so maybe things changed a bit? I tried it for 5, 10, 15 mililons of iterations and Compiled is always slower.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/03/to-compile-or-not-to-compile.html

Compiled helps only if you instantiate it once and re-use it multiple times. If you're creating a compiled regex in the for loop then it obviously will perform worse. Can you show us your sample code?

Comment: Added the code, I already told that I compile once and run 500 times.

Comment: But, your code instantiates (and thus compiles) the regex inside the loop, so you are in fact compiling 500 times.

Comment: Yes it generates 1000 compiled regex and then run same regex 500 times? Where is the problem?

Comment: So you are doing a very slow operation 1000 times and hoping that speeds up a fast operation done 500 times? You should compile the regex once, then run the regex probably 10,000 times (at least).

Comment: @Domenic Read the code, it's 1000 compiled regex and *each* executed 500 times

Answer (score 5):

The problem with this benchmark is that compiled Regexes have the overhead of creating a whole new assembly and loading it into the AppDomain.

The scenario where compiled Regex was designed for (I believe -- I didn't design them) is having tens of Regexes executed millions of times, not thousands of Regexes executed thousands of times. If you're not going to execute a Regex in the realm of a million times, you probably won't even make up for the time to JIT compile it.

Comment: I think you are right, somehow I assume the performance benefit can quickly kick in if we use more than 100 times, but doesn't look like the case.

Answer (score 4):

This is almost certainly an indication that your benchmark code is written incorrectly vs. compiled regex's being slower than interpreted ones.  There is a lot of work that went into making compiled regex's performant.

Now that we have the code can look at a few specific things that need updating

1. This code doesn't account for the JIT costs of the method.  It should run the code once to get the JIT costs out of the way and then run it again and measure
2. Why is `lock` used at all?  It's completely unnecessary
3. Benchmarks should use `StopWatch` not `DateTime`
4. To get a good comparison between Compiled and not compiled you should test the performance of a single compiled `Regex` and single non-compiled `Regex` matching N times.  Not N of each matching at most once per regex.

Comment: @dr. evil I've read the blog post and I still think it's incorrect. There are several issues with are simply not accounted for in the testing (several of which I've mentioned and more I will add shortly).

Comment: I updated my code as well, slightly better version of the code from that blog post

Comment: All of the things you said is correct but still doesn't change the fact that compiled regexes are slow

Comment: No, the "fact" that compiled regexes are slow is completely false, as proven by people who have written much more competent and accurate benchmarks than you have showing the opposite.

Comment: @dr. evil sorry I disagree. Your test is not testing a compiled regex in the scenario that it's optimized for. Sure if you put it in a different scenario it will be slower.  If you put it into the scenario it's meant to be used for (one regex used many many times) then it will be faster

Comment: Sorry to get antagonistic, but when you lay out an absolutist answer like that when you clearly don't understand how benchmarking works, it's easy to get a bit annoyed.

Comment: @Domenic clearly you can't read code either, it's 1000 regex, and *each* executed 500 times. Secondly if you do have a better benchmark on this please share.

Comment: @JaredPar Looks like JIT cost has a big effect as you pointed out, I run the code twice (updated the code) this should solve the JIT problem (I guess). If not any suggestions. It's still performing slightly slower though or without any gain. When the expected gain kicks in, after 100.000 execution? Is there any clear defined scenarios where compiled regex is actually useful? In this test 1000 compiled regex each ran 500 times still slower than compiled ones, am I missing anything?