# Regex Match Performance Issue For Spintax Parser

Tags: c#, regex, spintax

I'm writing an application that is intended to process thousands of articles/entries with large number of spintax in the following format:

```
{Hello|Hi} {World|There!}, how are you?
```

However when I run the application with profiler I noticed the part where Regex is handled is hogging a lot of resource and my application eventually crash due to out of memory issue. Can anyone suggest a way to improve my code or a better way to parse the spintax?

```
public static String Spin(String text)
{
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"\{[^\{\}]*\}");
        Random rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        while (true)
        {
            Match m = reg.Match(text);
            if (!m.Success) break;
            String[] parts = m.Value.TrimStart('{').TrimEnd('}').Split('|');
            int i = rand.Next(parts.Length);
            text = text.Substring(0, m.Index) + parts[i] + text.Substring(m.Index + m.Length);
        }
        return text;
  }
```

Comment: Is it the actual regex you're using that's slow or is it the rest of the code? You could use possessive quantifiers to speed up the process in order to avoid backtracking if that's causing you trouble. However, I don't think it will change much.

Comment: I think specifically it's the regex.match part that is hogging the most resource. The rest of the code is fine.

Comment: I see your code does not support nested spintaxes. Is it intended?

Comment: No it is not intended. It is supposed to support nested spintaxes however I have no clue how to achieve that.

Comment: What fraction of whole method execution time (in %) regex.match takes?

Comment: It's unlikely that anything in your `Spin` method is causing a memory leak. The memory problem is somewhere else in your code. Also, if this is going to be called thousands of times, you should make the regex static (defined outside the method), and use the `RegexOptions.Compiled` option when creating it.

Comment: @JimMischel - Initially I agreed with you regarding `static` and `RegexOptions.Compiled`, but hm, I've implemented both and they don't seem to make much of a difference (http://ideone.com/FHYC4E). I tried using a much longer string in this version, too. Perhaps the compiler already optimizes for these factors, somehow.

Comment: @acheong87: Define the regex outside the method: `static Regex reg = new Regex(@"\{[^\{\}]*\}", RegexOptions.Compiled);`. Don't create a new one inside the method. The idea is that you define it once and use it many times.

Comment: @JimMischel - Hm, I create it only once, in the `main` method. It's reused by through the iterations, I think.

Comment: @acheong87: My apologies. I misread the code. Try it with 1,000,000 iterations rather than 1,000. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6005226/56778 for a little more context.

Comment: @JimMischel - Hm. With Ideone's 15-second execution limit I could not go past 2,000. But I plotted some benchmarks for 100, 200, 500, 1000, and 2000 runs on a logarithm scale, and it's pretty much linear, _i.e._ I don't see it curving in; in fact it's curving out. I have a feeling that compiled regexes are only useful for more complicated regexes: that is, maybe a simple alternation (`|`) may already be optimized even without explicitly having the regex compiled. One day I'll do some testing at home and report back.

Answer (score 7):

I have implemented my fast version (no `Regex`, no `Split`, no `Substring`, no `Replace` and other string manipulation methods). To copy string I'm using `String.CopyTo` which copies symbols to a plain `char` array.

This code fully supports nested Spintaxes (potentially unlimited depth). One restriction is maximum number of options per Spintax, currently it is 100, but can be changed to 1000 or more... Another restriction is maximum length of input string, it is 100000 now, but can be increased too.

Concerning performance - my tests showed that this code is >15 times faster than any optimised Regex solution (including Jim Mischel's one) and ~5 times faster than versions which are using Substring and other String manipulation methods. I have tested this in Release mode with Optimize Code setting in VS 2012.

```
    static int[] partIndices = new int[100];
    static int[] depth = new int[100];
    static char[] symbolsOfTextProcessed = new char[100000];

    public static String SpinEvenMoreFaster(String text)
    {
        int cur = SpinEvenMoreFasterInner(text, 0, text.Length, 0);
        return new String(symbolsOfTextProcessed, 0, cur);
    }

    public static int SpinEvenMoreFasterInner(String text, int start, int end, int symbolIndex)
    {
        int last = start;
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            if (text[i] == '{')
            {
                int k = 1;
                int j = i + 1;
                int index = 0;
                partIndices[0] = i;
                depth[0] = 1;
                for (; j < end && k > 0; j++)
                {
                    if (text[j] == '{')
                        k++;
                    else if (text[j] == '}')
                        k--;
                    else if (text[j] == '|')
                    {
                        if (k == 1)
                        {
                            partIndices[++index] = j;
                            depth[index] = 1;
                        }
                        else
                            depth[index] = k;
                    }
                }
                if (k == 0)
                {
                    partIndices[++index] = j - 1;
                    int part = rand.Next(index);
                    text.CopyTo(last, symbolsOfTextProcessed, symbolIndex, i - last);
                    symbolIndex += i - last;
                    if (depth[part] == 1)
                    {
                        text.CopyTo(partIndices[part] + 1, symbolsOfTextProcessed, symbolIndex, partIndices[part + 1] - partIndices[part] - 1);
                        symbolIndex += partIndices[part + 1] - partIndices[part] - 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        symbolIndex = SpinEvenMoreFasterInner(text, partIndices[part] + 1, partIndices[part + 1], symbolIndex);
                    }
                    i = j - 1;
                    last = j;
                }
            }
        }
        text.CopyTo(last, symbolsOfTextProcessed, symbolIndex, end - last);
        return symbolIndex + end - last;
    }
```

Comment: Holy, !@#$! You're right. This is way faster. [Ideone evidence here.](http://ideone.com/ItZ4y2) SpinRE: 03.760s. SpinNoRE: 00.795s. SpinSergey: 00.148s. +1.

Comment: Thanks:) I'm curious if OP is still monitoring this page:) But problem itself was interesting!

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot http://screencast.com/t/0Go7HHxTi where you can see a three different spinner codes and SergeyS is the best spinner code so far. I hope your code @SergeyS, can improve more because I wrote a code that generates 1 to N level and all the spinner code barely can't go to 20th level

Answer (score 4):

Here's a non-Regex alternative.

**Update 2012-12-27 (see [new ideone demo](http://ideone.com/C3vjBw))**

1. Optimized OP's code to use static members instead of declaring variables within the loop, use `RegexOptions.Compiled`, and use `Substring` instead of `TrimLeft` and `TrimRight`. These optimizations cut down execution time of OP's code by nearly 33%.
2. Updated `SpinNoRE` to handle arbitrarily nested spintaxes, optimized code, and added comments.
3. Renamed `Spin` and `SpinFaster` to `SpinRE` and `SpinNoRE` respectively, for clarity.
4. Updated test case with nested example. OP's code was much, much slower to handle nested spintaxes (understandably, since every level of nesting forces an additional regex match).

New [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/C3vjBw) available; code below (comments available in demo; see link):

```
public static String SpinNoRE(String text)
{
    int i, j, e = -1;
    char[] curls = new char[] {'{', '}'};
    text += '~';

    do
    {
        i =  e;
        e = -1;
        while ((i = text.IndexOf('{', i+1)) != -1)
        {
            j = i;
            while ((j = text.IndexOfAny(curls, j+1)) != -1 && text[j] != '}')
            {
                if (e == -1) e = i;
                i = j;
            }
            if (j != -1)
            {
                parts = text.Substring(i+1, (j-1)-(i+1-1)).Split('|');
                text = text.Remove(i, j-(i-1)).Insert(i, parts[rand.Next(parts.Length)]);
            }
        }
    }
    while (e-- != -1);

    return text.Remove(text.Length-1);
}
```

Result:

```
Input Text:       Oh! {{I'm|You're} here!|How are you{ doing{|, {buddy|pal|guy}}|}?}
Testing SpinRE:   Oh! You're here!
Testing SpinRE:   Oh! How are you doing?
Testing SpinRE:   Oh! How are you?
Testing SpinRE:   Oh! How are you doing, buddy?
Testing SpinRE:   Oh! I'm here!
Testing SpinRE:   Oh! How are you doing, guy?
Testing SpinRE:   Oh! How are you doing?
Testing SpinRE:   Oh! I'm here!
Testing SpinRE:   Oh! I'm here!
Testing SpinRE:   Oh! How are you doing?
Testing SpinNoRE: Oh! How are you doing, buddy?
Testing SpinNoRE: Oh! You're here!
Testing SpinNoRE: Oh! How are you?
Testing SpinNoRE: Oh! How are you?
Testing SpinNoRE: Oh! You're here!
Testing SpinNoRE: Oh! I'm here!
Testing SpinNoRE: Oh! How are you doing?
Testing SpinNoRE: Oh! How are you?
Testing SpinNoRE: Oh! How are you doing, buddy?
Testing SpinNoRE: Oh! I'm here!

Time elapsed over 100,000 runs of each in alternation:

SpinRE:           03.686s
SpinNoRE:         00.921s
```

(It's been more than 6 years since I touched C#. Please forgive and point out any mistakes.)

Comment: Doe not work for nested Spintaxes. Try this for example: "{{I'm|you're} here!|how are you?}"

Comment: @SergeyS - I was only trying to emulate OP's regex solution, which didn't support nested Spintaxes either. I was more trying to demonstrate how much faster this could be without regular expressions, not provide a full Spintax solution.

Comment: @SergeyS - My apologies. I initially read your comment on OP's question about his code not supporting nested spintaxes, and I assumed that to be the case. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: well done! However I have found one little bug in your solution. Try this string to repro it: "Curly {}{brackets|braces} here!". If interested - take a look at my code, I did not use Split and Substring and it is ~5 times faster than yours.

Comment: @SergeyS - Thanks! I won't bother to fix the bug, since it seems your solution is superior anyway. I'm primarily a C/C++ developer myself, so I was looking up equivalent functions for `strpos`, `strtok`, etc. on MSDN, haha. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to get that "low" in level.

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot http://screencast.com/t/0Go7HHxTi where you can see a three different spinner codes and SergeyS is the best spinner code so far. I hope your code @SergeyS, can improve more because I wrote a code that generates 1 to N level and all the spinner code barely can't go to 20th level

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a few changes to your code. First, move the regular expression definition out of the method and use the `RegexOptions.Compiled` option to reduce the setup time per call. Also, move creation of the random number generator out of the heavily used method.

Also, you can eliminate much unnecessary string searching by telling the regular expression where to start matching. This is important if you end up doing many iterations of the loop. The idea is that if you've already done the replacements up to position M in the string, there's no reason to check those for matches because there won't be any.

You can eliminate the calls to `TrimStart` and `TrimEnd` by replacing the expression with:

```
String[] parts = m.Value.Substring(1, m.Value.Length-2).Split('|');
```

You already know that the string starts with `{` and ends with `}`, and doesn't have either of those two characters anywhere in the middle, so all you have to do is chop off the first and last characters. There's no reason to incur the cost of the temporary strings created by `TrimStart` and `TrimEnd`.

Another possibility would be to add a capture group to the regular expression (placing parentheses around the part you want to capture), and operating on the captured text rather than the entire matched expression.

Putting all those suggestiong together leads to:

```
static Regex reg = new Regex(@"\{([^\{\}]*)\}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
static Random rand = new Random();
public static String Spin(String text)
{
    int matchPos = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        Match m = reg.Match(text, matchPos);
        if (!m.Success) break;
        String[] parts = m.Groups[1].Value.Split('|');
        int i = rand.Next(parts.Length);
        text = text.Substring(0, m.Index) + parts[i] + text.Substring(m.Index + m.Length);
        matchPos = m.Index;
    }
    return text;
}
```

That said, this won't support nesting, and making a regex solution that does support nesting is likely to be somewhat difficult. It's also less than optimum in terms of speed because it spends a lot of time building and rebuilding the `text` string. With a little thought, you can optimize it a bit more, but it will never be as fast as an optimized custom parser solution like [SergyS supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14047581/56778).

If speed is paramount, then you'll want a custom parser. The regex version won't be as fast, but if it's fast enough it has the benefit of being smaller, and easier to understand and modify than a custom parser.