# Regular Expression with brackets - performance

Tags: c#, regex, match

Today i had to find values between brackets in multiple strings (one of them below)

```
[xyz]=[something][xsd]=[123;#blabla][abc]=[2013-12-31 10:00]
```

Only thing i knew was names preceeding values: xyz, xsd and abc

The regex I am currently using is: `\[(xsd)(?:\]=\[)([^\)]+?)\]` which gives me two groups (a name - xsd and value - 123;#blabla).

Hovewer i was thinking about another regex: `(?<=\[xsd\]=\[)(.*?)(?=\])` which gives only a group with a value

Can someone tell me which one is better/faster ? Or maybe there's a simpler expression to get a value? :)

Comment: Define "better", if you mean "faster" then just benchmark it.

Comment: If you are interested in regex performance, [this discussion about compiled and interpreted expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004819/why-compiled-regex-performance-is-slower-than-intrepreted-regex) may also be useful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that one of these expressions are better, because lazy quantifiers are not used, and you don't need to extract the value since it is the full result:

```
(?<=\[xsd]=\[)[^]]+(?=])


(?<=\[(?>xyz|xsd|abc)]=\[)[^]]+(?=])
```

first pattern details:

```
(?<=             # lookbehind assertion (means: preceded by)
    \[xsd]=\[    # literal: [xsd]=[  ,note that ] doesn't need to be escaped
)                # close the lookbehind
[^]]+            # all charaters except ], one or more times
(?=])            # lookahead assertion: (followed by ] )
```

Using a greedy quantifier with a reduced character class is always faster than using the dot with a lazy quantifier, because in the second case, the regex engine must check for each characters the lazy quantifier eat, if the subpattern after the lazy quantifier matches. With a greedy quantifier, the regex engine eat all that is possible and doesn't check anything.

Comment: I modified your first expression a little and it is working for me: (?<=\\[xsd\\]=\[)[^]+?(?=\\])
If i use greedy quantifiers i get wrong results in specific cases. Arent they better than greedy quantifiers?

Comment: @mctl87: did you try the expressions in real code or with a regex tester?

Comment: At first i only tried your expression with a regex tester but it seems like your expression works in real code and mine in regex tester. Could you tell me why there's difference ?

Comment: First at all, you must always use a tester designed for your target language since regex engines are different in javascript, c#, php, java... For C# and .net languages you can use regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: @mctl87: I will add details for the first pattern in my answer.

Comment: @mctl87: In particular implementations of javascript `[^]` is seen as the negation of an empty character class and means all possible characters (newlines included).

Comment: Thank you Casimir, it explains a lot to me.