# Make string checker more efficient

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am using the following code to check if a string is contained within another string -

```
foreach (string testrecord in testlist)
{
   foreach (string realrecord in reallist)
   {         
      if ((Regex.Replace(testrecord , "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "")
                .Contains((
                    Regex.Replace(realrecord, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", ""))) 
          && 
           ((Regex.Replace(realrecord, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "") != "") 
          && 
           ((Regex.Replace(realrecord, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "").Length >= 4)))))
      {

         matchTextBox.AppendText("Match: " + testrecord + " & " + realrecord + Environment.NewLine);

      }
   }

}
```

However the runtime for this to finish is taking quite a while. Since I added the special character regex removal the runtime is taking a lot longer however the regex is definitely required.

Is there a more efficient way of applying this regex? I tried to add it to the foreach string variables however you cannot alter them as they are in a foreach loop.

Comment: Implement the string processing yourself if you need the performance. As far as I can tell all you're doing is restricting the character set.

Comment: Compile the regex before using it will speed things up. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004819/why-compiled-regex-performance-is-slower-than-intrepreted-regex

Comment: For a start, you might want to run `Regex.Replace(realrecord, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "")` only *once* and cache the result in a variable rather than calling it three times per iteration.

Comment: `!=""` seems to be a duplicate of `Length>=4`

Comment: @O.R.Mapper he should do that even regardless of performance. It is copy&paste programming at the moment.

Comment: Have you proven that `myString.Contains("otherString")` is too slow, or is this an assumption? Also, a regex can operate on multiple lines, so you might be able to compress the `foreach` into a single regex call if you let us know what it is exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @usr: True. And while we're at it, `Regex.Replace(testrecord , "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "")` is invoked once per iteration of the inner loop, even though its result doesn't seem to change in the inner loop at all, so it could just as well be called once in the outer loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimized version:

```
// Do not put text into matchTextBox direct:
// it makes the control re-painting each time you change the text
// Instead, collect all the text into StringBuffer  
StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder(); 

// Pull out as much as you can from the inner loop,
// that's why I've changed the loops' order:
// first loop on reallist, then on testlist
foreach (string realrecord in reallist) {
  // Cache Regex.Replace result
  String realCleaned = Regex.Replace(realrecord, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");

  // Test as early as possible
  if (realCleaned.Length < 4)
    continue;

  // You don't need to test realCleaned != "";: realCleaned.Length < 4 is enough

  foreach (string testrecord in testlist) {
    // Cache Regex.Replace result: it's a little bit overshoot here, but if some
    // more tests are added it'll be helpful
    String testCleaned = Regex.Replace(testrecord, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");

    if (testCleaned.Contains(realCleaned))
      Sb.AppendLine("Match: " + testrecord + " & " + realrecord);
  }  
}

// At last matchTextBox.Text change
matchTextBox.AppendText(Sb.ToString());
```

Comment: First run 30 minutes, run with your alterations - 14 minutes, gold star Dmitry, twice as fast!

Answer (score 1):

This should be a bit quicker (one regex operation per `testrecord`):

```
var strippedRealList = reallist.Select(s => Regex.Replace(s, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", ""))
                               .Where(s => s.Length >= 4)
                               .ToArray();

foreach (string realrecord in reallist)
{
   strippedRealList.Where(s => realrecord.Contains(s))
                   .ToList()
                   .ForEach(s =>
                            matchTextBox.AppendText("Match: "
                                                  + s
                                                  + " & "
                                                  + realrecord
                                                  + Environment.NewLine));

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I wonder that you are using Regex to achieve your purpose ignoring the fact that you can also achieve this by only using .Contains() method such that your code should be simple and faster then before

```
foreach (string testrecord in testlist)
{
   foreach (string realrecord in reallist)
   {         
      if(testrecord.Contains(realrecord))
         {
         matchTextBox.AppendText("Match: " + testrecord + " & " + realrecord + Environment.NewLine);
         }
   }

}
```

Comment: -1: The regex is clearly needed to remove characters that aren't letters or digits before comparing..