# Understanding the ramifications of CultureInvariant and IgnoreCase on [A-Za-z]

Tags: c#, regex, case-insensitive, culture

If I create a `Regex` based on this pattern: `@"[A-Za-z]+"`, does the set that it matches change at all by adding `RegOptions.IgnoreCase` if I'm already using `RegOptions.CultureInvariant` (due to [issues like this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=turkish%20i))?  I think this is an obvious "no, it's just redundant and repetitive".  And in my tests that's what I've shown, but I wonder if I'm missing something due to confirmation bias.

Please correct me if I'm wrong on this point, but I believe that I definitely need to use the `CultureInvariant` though, since I also do not know what the culture will be.  [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#Invariant)

**Note:** this is not the actual pattern I need to use, just the simplest critical portion of it.  The full pattern is: `@"[A-Za-z0-9\s!\\#$(),.:;=@'\-{}|/&]+"`, in case there is actually some strange behavior surrounding symbols, case, and culture.  No, I didn't create the pattern, I'm just consuming it, can't change it, and I realize the `|` is not needed before `/&`.

If I could change the pattern...

1. Pattern `"[a-z]"` with both `CultureInvariant` and `IgnoreCase`
   would be functionally equivalent to `"[A-Za-z]"` using only
   `CultureInvariant` correct?
2. Assuming #1 is correct, which would be more efficient, and why?  I would guess the shorter pattern is more efficient to evaluate against, but I don't know how the internals work right now to say that with much confidence.

Comment: `CultureInvariant` has no affect on `[A-Za-z]` because the Turkish i (or any other culture specific characters) is not in the range you have specified.

Comment: Maybe run a loop over all possible 65536 chars? You could even test all 2 char sequences.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence I discovered when researching my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004819/why-compiled-regex-performance-is-slower-than-intrepreted-regex/6005226#6005226 indicates that `[A-Za-z]` will be faster than using `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`.

Comment: Have you considered using the built-in classes as described at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#WordCharacter?

Comment: If you're already using `CultureInvariant` with `[A-Za-z]`, changing to `[a-z]` (or `[A-Z]`) and adding `IgnoreCase` will not change the set of symbols matched. There is a one-to-one mapping between `[A-Z]` and `[a-z]`. Nor will the casing rules affect matching the digits `[0-9]`, since there aren't upper- and lower-case digits.

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks, I saw you had posted your comment as I was answering my own question.  I think it is basically in alignment with the conclusion I came to, only you didn't have the working knowledge that I *wasn't* "already using" `CultureInvariant`.  I was only considering using it.  So you approached it from a different angle.

Comment: @Eris This is really vauge and not really helpful.  As I stated, I can't actually change the pattern, I was just curious about the effect of the `RegexOptions` on different patterns.  Besides, unless you have a something more specific in mind, I don't see how they would circumvent the 1-1 mapping issue that Jim pointed out in his comment.

Comment: @JimMischel Thank you for the comment about efficiency, and that wonderful answer you linked.  +1

Comment: @JimMischel I'm sorry, I did say if I'm already using `CultureInvariant` in my question.  I have gotten myself all mixed today.  I will adjust the question and leave it unanswered to see if my answer is fallacious in any way.

Comment: @JimMischel I was going to adjust the question, but I feel like the question was valid.  My earlier comment to you was just wrong.  I got myself confused by assuming `IgnoreCase`+Turkish 'I' was the issue, when `CultureInvariant` was the real issue. As the question stands, the simple answer I still think is no, the set it matches does not change when `CultureInvariant` is already being used, and `IgnoreCase` is added.

Answer (score 2):

Using this program we can test all possible two-letter sequences:

```
static void Main()
{
    var defaultRegexOptions = RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Singleline;
    var regex1 = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z]+$", defaultRegexOptions);
    var regex2 = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z]+$", defaultRegexOptions | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    ParallelEnumerable.Range(char.MinValue, char.MaxValue - char.MinValue + 1)
        .ForAll(firstCharAsInt =>
        {
            var buffer = new char[2];
            buffer[0] = (char)firstCharAsInt;

            for (int i = char.MinValue; i <= char.MaxValue; i++)
            {
                buffer[1] = (char)i;

                var str = new string(buffer);

                if (regex1.IsMatch(str) != regex2.IsMatch(str))
                    Console.WriteLine("dfjkgnearjkgh");
            }
        });
}
```

There could be differences in longer sequences but I think that's quite unlikely. This is strong evidence that there is no difference.

The program takes 20 minutes to run.

Unfortunately, this answer does not provide any insight into *why* this is.

Comment: +1 for the effort, and I realize how a lot of interpretations of my question could yield a pragmatic answer like this, and I also realize my question could be boiled down to a simple "No" in response to "does the set that it matches change by adding IgnoreCase", but as you said it gives no insight, and that's really what I was after - understanding the ramifications of using those flags in conjunction with a pattern that is already case-insensitive over that range of characters within the latin alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

So I had a fundamental misunderstanding of the way this all works.  I think this is what was throwing me off...

```
Regex regex = new Regex("[A-Za-z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

...will return `false` for `regex.IsMatch("ı")`, but `true` for `regex.IsMatch("İ")`.  If I remove the `IgnoreCase` it returns `false` for both, and if I used `CultureInvariant` (with or without `IgnoreCase`) it will return `false` regardless, and this basically boils down to what Scott Chamberlain said in his comment.  Thank you Scott.

Ultimately I *want* "İ" and "ı" to both be rejected, and I just got myself all turned around by bringing `IgnoreCase` into the mix before I had even considered `CultureInvariant`.  If I drop `IgnoreCase` and add `CultureInvariant` then I can keep the pattern as is and have it match what I want it to.

If I were able to change the pattern to just `"[A-Z]"` then I could use both flags and still get the desired behavior.  But the bit about changing the pattern, and which would be more efficient was just curiosity.  I don't want to get into all the issues that could arise from that discussion, and all the ways I could change pattern.  My concern was with culture, case-insensitivity, and these two `RegexOptions`.

To summarize, I need to drop `IgnoreCase` and then the entire issue surrounding culture goes away.  *If* the pattern were `a-z` or `A-Z` and I needed to use `IgnoreCase` to match both upper and lower, then I would *need* to use `CultureInvariant` also.