# Regex taking too much time in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a Regex which I am applying on the email body to remove some characters and it is taking too much time to evaluate.

```
Regex MailRegex = new Regex(@"[\s]*<(https|http|tes:|file:|mailto:|BLOCKED::|ftp:|gopher:|nntp:|prospero:|telnet:|news:|wais:|outlook:)[\\w\b\r\t\\e\na-zA-Z0-9 \\ / : ; ' # = ! _ \- & . , @ ? * ( ) ^ ` ~ % $ ! | + ""]+>", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

MailRegex.Replace("Email Body", "");//My Application taking time here
```

I think this might be because of catastrophic backtracking...

Any ideas how I can solve or optimize this `MailRegex`?

Comment: is email Body is a variable or string as shown above?

Comment: Try `@"\s*<(?>https?|te(?:s|lnet):|f(?:ile|tp):|mailto:|BLOCKED::|gopher:|nntp:|prospero:|news:|wais:|outlook:)[^>]*>"`, try at https://regex101.com/r/DziojF/1.

Comment: There is no backtracking in this regex. Please provide a *reproducible* example. How did you determine that the regex is taking too much time?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: There is backtracking here due to the alternatives that match at the same location.

Comment: I'd still like to see a *reproducible* example. This regex is too fast to measure when run against 5-6 lines of text. What does "too much time" mean?

Comment: @TejasPatadiya use BenchmarkDotNet to determine the actual performance of the regular expression. Are you sure you aren't measuring something else? Even for 100 lines, the regex is very fast

Comment: Why does " / : ; ' # = ! _ \- & . , @ ? * ( ) ^ ` ~ % $ ! | +" have spaces inbetween everything?

Comment: The first backslash here: `\\w\b\r\t\\e\na-zA-Z0-9` is probably not what you want, it matches the backslash character and the letter w. `\w`and `a-zA-Z0-9` are the same. ` \\ /` should probably be `\/`. I'd say, take a good hard look at your regex and clean it up a little.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have a one email body which has around 210000 lines and regex is taking aroung 3-4 hours for this.

Comment: 1) One body means you only execute that regex once, right? Do away with `RegexOptions.Compiled` => See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004819/why-compiled-regex-performance-is-slower-than-intrepreted-regex  2) You haven't escaped special chars. Without more info I just took a shot at reducing the second half to what you seem to be wanting to match: `[\s]*<(https|http|tes:|file:|mailto:|BLOCKED::|ftp:|gopher:|nntp:|prospero:|telnet:|news:|wais:|outlook:)[\w\r\t\e\n\\\/\:\;\'\#\=\!_\-\&\.\,\@\?\*\(\)\^\`\~\%\$\!\|\+\"]+>` Does that speed things up?

Comment: The initial `[\s]*` does not need the square brackets, but it does not really do anything useful unless you want to work with the entire matched test including the initial optional white space. Replacing the `[\s]*` with `\b` (a word boundary) should give a very similar effect.

Comment: From the list of strings I suspect that the section `https|http|` should also have colons and so be written `https:|http:|`. The big character class also includes the colon. So I suggest removing the colons from _all_ of the list of words and possibly adding an explicit match for one or more colons between the list of words and the big character class. So the middle becomes `|wais|outlook):+[\w\b` (also changed the `\\w` issue noted by @LocEngineer).